# Performant creation of sparse (stiffness) matrix

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, scipy

i'm currently implementing a small finite element sim. using Python/Numpy, and i am looking for an efficient way to create the global stiffness matrix:

1) I think that the creation of a sparse matrix from smaller element stiffness matrices should be done using `coo_matrix()`. However, can i extend an existing `coo_matrix`, or should i create it from the final i,j and v lists?

2) Currently, i am creating the i and j lists from the smaller element stiffness matrix using list comprehensions and concatenating them. Is there a better way to create these lists?

3) Creation of the data vector: Same question, are python lists preferred over numpy vectors due to the easy extension possibilities?

4) Of course i am open for any advices :). Thank You!

Here is a small example of my current plan to do the global assembly to make clear what i intend:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

#2 nodes, 3 dof per node
locations = [0, 6]
nNodes = 2
dof =3
totSize = nNodes * dof
Ke = np.array([[1,1,1, 2,2,2],
              [1,1,1, 2,2,2],
              [1,1,1, 2,2,2],
              [2,2,2, 3,3,3],
              [2,2,2, 3,3,3],
              [2,2,2, 3,3,3]])

I = []
J = []
#generate rowwise i and j lists:
i = [ idx + u for i in range(totSize) for  idx in locations for u in range(dof)  ]
j = [ idx + u  for  idx in locations for u in range(dof) for i in range(totSize) ]
I += i
J += J

Data = Ke.flatten()

cMatrix = coo_matrix( (Data, (i,j)), )
```

Comment: That `i` at the line that computes `j` overwrites into `i` which was computed at the line before.

Comment: @Divakar huh? You mean the `i` in the list comprehension? In python 3, comprehension don't have leaky scope...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah I see. Yeah I am on python2.7 and was overwriting into `i` at that step.

Comment: @Divakar get with the times, man ;) But really, Python 3.6 is probably the best version of Python ever, especially with the new `dict` implementation.

Comment: And people are having problems loading third party packages in 3.6.  Or at least were when 3.6 was still in beta.  My `numpy` runs on 3.5, but most `numpy` questions and answers assume 2.7.  `np.genfromtxt` is still biased toward bytestrings.

Comment: Look at the code for `sparse.bmat` to see how it assembles smaller matrices into one large one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this post, I would try to focus on performance issue specific to the creation of lists `i`, `j` and finally matrix `cMatrix`.

Under those loop/list comprehensions, you are basically performing element-wise additions of `locations` and `range(dof)`. Porting over to NumPy, we could leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) there. Finally, to simulate for `range(totSize)` again in those comprehensions, we could `tile` the final addition result with `np.tile`. We will use it as its flattened version for indexing into columns of the sparse matrix and its transposed flattened version for rows.

Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
idx0 = (np.asarray(locations)[:,None] + np.arange(dof)).ravel()
J = np.tile(idx0[:,None],totSize)
cMatrix = coo_matrix( (Data, (J.ravel('F'),J.ravel())), )
```